# Error while compiling for SwiftUI (Type check)

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I get the error when compiling this if/else statement in my view. Seems like its typed well enough but it produces an error. `modes` is an array of objects. The index is an Int from an enum value

```
public extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    func elementIndex() -> Self.AllCases.Index {
        return Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
    }
}
...
var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            //compiler barfs below:
            let c: Int = modes.count - 1 as! Int
            let index: Int = current_mode.currentMode.elementIndex() as! Int
            if (index > c) {
                print("nope")
            } else {
                print("ok")
            }
```

How can I write this so it compiles?

I thought it was typed well enough to compile.

Comment: Procedural code like that doesn't go in a `View` `body`. You could put it in `onAppear` or `task`. It also appears like you `body` may not be within a `View` at all. You may want to check out some SwiftUI tutorials (Apple's or Hacking with Swift's)

Comment: I actually want to optionally set text into Text controls... I just didn't supply all the code, just what is necessary. So if an index is out of an array's range, set text to "none" and if in range, use an object in the array for the string.

Comment: SwiftUI tutorials would be a good bet

Comment: Unrelated but a forced cast `Int` to `Int` is pointless. Don't you get the `Forced cast of 'Int' to same type has no effect` warning?

Answer (score 0):

I re-thought how to approach the problem. I added a `@State` text variable and use that in my `Text` object. Later in a `.onAppear` I check and if possible, I update the state var and it gets implemented (refresh UI).

I was confused because you can do if/else checks in determining whether to include certain views into the hierarchy - just not doing what I was trying to do. I solved my problem. Thanks to all who spent time reading any of this.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI doesn't allow to print inside the View Body. it can be used as:

```
if let index = modes.firstIndex(of: mode), index > c {
 Text("NOPE == \(mode)")
} else {
  Text("OK == \(mode)")
}
```

move it outside the body :

```
 var c: Int {
        modes.count - 1
    }
```